# Copy data from one table to another table in MySQL in batches based on datetime

Tags: mysql

I have been working on copying data from one table to another (Archival) & being doing that manually today. I have ben trying to select data from one table to another table based on datetime. Data for 01st Jan is inserted/committed, similarly data for 02nd Jan is inserted/committed & this runs in iterations until the max date is reached based on the source table max date.

I have a table named test_data with a datetime column named check_time & a similar table is created named test_arc.

I also tried to declare a variable that gets the MIN(check_time) from test_data & starts iterations from that date & goes all the way till the MAX(check_time) but that also seems to fail to set values. Please see what I attempted in the link below.

This seems quite feasible in MS SQL & works like a charm but I can't get the same logic to work on MySQL. I have to agree I am not well versed with MySQL.

I tested using DB Fiddle but keep running into issues. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

DB Fiddle Link: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f20dfefe1477993c870dde178825380f

MS SQL:

```
DECLARE @MinDate DATETime = '2022-01-01 00:00:00',
        @MaxDate DATETime = getdate();  
SELECT  TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @MinDate, @MaxDate) + 1)
CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate),120) as 
startdate,CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(DAY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY 
a.object_id) - 1, @MinDate) +'23:59:59.999',120) as Enddate
FROM    sys.all_objects a
CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects b;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=021b7a6efd0167e26156eee607649f52

Comment: @Akina Thank You that solves the variable part of it. We have a function in MS SQL using which we can iterate using SSIS. I am trying to do something similar in MySQL so the procedure & fetch data for Day1 -> Commit, then Day2 -> Commit & that runs in iterations. I added the MS SQL code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this code:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_data` ( IN date_from DATE, 
                                 IN date_till DATE )
BEGIN
    -- adjust input dates according to the values present in the table
    SELECT GREATEST(DATE(MIN(check_time)), date_from),
           LEAST(DATE(MAX(check_time)), date_till)
    INTO date_from, date_till
    FROM test_data;
    -- copy the data day-by-day
    WHILE date_from <= date_till DO
        INSERT IGNORE INTO test_arc
        SELECT * 
        FROM test_data 
        WHERE check_time >= date_from AND check_time < date_from + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
        SET date_from = date_from + INTERVAL 1 DAY;
    END WHILE;
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=24475863d72932cb263643ba11bf8d76) with debug output.

You may add a transaction into the cycle body if needed.

Comment: Thanks You Akina, the logic seems to work as charm :)